# How to pass query string in customer.xml?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, url

I want to add Query string on customer/account/login/ page from the customer.xml
Below are the code:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
```

I want my URL like:

```
customer/account/login?tab=register
```

Is there possibility to update URL from the customer.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add following code it works

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title">
    <label>About Us</label>
    <url>customer/account/login?tab=test</url>  <!-- can use full url also -->
    <title>About Us</title>
    <prepare>true</prepare> <!-- set true if adding base url param -->
    <position>1</position>
    <liParams/>
    <aParams>class="top-link-about-us"</aParams>
    <beforeText></beforeText>
    <afterText></afterText>
</action>
```

Comment: Hi Shyam,
Your code working fine.
<url>customer/account/login?tab=test</url>